# Input field pattern does not function right

Tags: html, validation, input, magento2

I created an input field pattern `[^a-z^A-Z]$`

What it should do is to NOT allow any letters ANYWHERE in the field. Only numbers and special symbols can be typed.

What happends is if I type like `35!` - its fine. If I add a letter `35!b` it say that `invalid format`. BUT if I then add another symbol, or number, like so `35!b1` then it magically is okey and works but it shouldint.

```
<item name="pattern" xsi:type="string">[^a-z^A-Z]$</item>
```

What did I do wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I do not know why, But this Pattern `^[^a-z^A-Z]{1,}$` solves the issue. I guess I had to specify that it can start anywhere, any letter without involving surrounding symbols.